# How to extract month name from custom date

Tags: excel

I have a CSV file which has date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format in column `A`. Here are the steps that i took to extract month from it.

1. Select the entire column `A` and click on `Format Cells`
2. In `Format Cells`, Click on `Custom` and used the string `mm/dd/yyyy` there
3. Clicked Ok
4. On column `D` (or any other column), I entered the following text `=TEXT(A1, "mmmm")`. This text is supposed to extract month number from column `A1` and convert into month. But it just copies the whole date there.

What i am missing here?

Comment: You might have *text-that-looks-like-a-date*.

Comment: how would i convert the text, which *looks-like-a-date* into a date so that i can extract month out of it?

Comment: Couple options. Try `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(A1),"mmmm")`.

Comment: If the cell has a green carrot in the left corner, it's text.  You could also have extra characters in the cell like a trailing space.  Try this - enter this formula in the adjacent cell =isnumber(A1) and replace A1 with your cell.  If false, there's another issue with the cell.

Comment: `isnumber(A6)` is `FALSE` but it could be due to the fact that the text in `A6` is `03/12/2019` which has two `/`

Comment: BigBen's suggestion should work.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates that you see are most likely strings that look like dates. You can convert them to actual dates using the `DATE(year, month, day)` function. Something like:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4), LEFT(A1,2), MID(A1,4,2))
```

(A1 contains the text date.) And then you can apply the date format to the column where you put this formula.

Comment: Excellent. So i just pasted `=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4), LEFT(A2,2), MID(A2,4,2))` text on a cell whose format was selected as `mmmm`. `A2` is the column which has *date-look-alike-text*. And the output was `March`. Thats what I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The text you specified is the syntax for getting the month name as a formula.

If you are just changing the number formatting of the cells, you specify the custom number format mmmm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Point two should be changed. In the `Format Cells` click on `Date` and select anything from the predefined formats:

[image]

Then the initial formula should work:

`=TEXT(A1, "mmmm")`